# Include assessment results of LimeSurvey in confirmation emails

Tags: limesurvey

I need to Include assessment results in confirmation emails

[This says it is possible](http://manual.limesurvey.org/wiki/Project_ideas_for_GSOC_2011) but I have no idea on how to do it
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **LimeSurvey 2.0 +** , you can **include the scores in your confirmation email** by using expression manager and equations type question. However, you cannot include assessment results in the email. For that you will have to disable confirmation email from Limesurvey and write your own custom script to create the content of the email (which you can easily do with the help of scores ) and send email from this script. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Not true : you can include assessment result in any email. Just need a Equation question type. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Or,

Add an Equation question type, code : ASSESVALUE. (for example, the last question).

Put inside question text {ASSESSMENT_CURRENT_TOTAL}, and use in your email {ASSESVALUE} (see http://manual.limesurvey.org/Assessments#Tips_.26_tricks)

You can use {if(ASSESVALUE>10,'Good','Bad')} see http://manual.limesurvey.org/Expression_Manager